# Do international laws require the detention and extradition of suspects?

Tags: united-states, politics, law

Barack Obama has said following:

> My continued expectation is that Russia or other countries that have
>   talked about potentially providing Mr Snowden asylum recognise that
>   they are a part of an international community and they should be
>   abiding by international law.

Is there in fact any [international law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_law) or [multilateral treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaties#Bilateral_and_multilateral_treaties), which would require countries to detain and extradite other countries' suspects?

If not, does any of mentioned countries have any bilateral treaties with US regarding the subject?

Comment: This is way too broad. To properly answer your question a whole academic course at International law is required.

Comment: International laws are made by agreement between nations, they exist when the (specific) nations have agreed to them. The USA has such agreements/laws with some countries and not others. The laws which do exist are complicated and they include various exceptions (for example they may depend on the type of crime, etc).

Comment: For example, newspapers wrote that the treaty between Hong Kong and the USA wouldn't cover "political crimes" or the extradition of political dissidents: and therefore the arrest warrant which the USA gave Hong Kong was for "unlawful use of a computer".

Comment: ChrisW: usually if someone talks about "international laws", that means something broader than bilateral treaties. Geneva convention would be good example of international law.

Comment: @vartec The Geneva convention is similar, in that it's a multilateral treaty (or treaties). Sovereign countries (unlike people) don't have "international laws" which they must obey without having agreed to them. The USA is an example of a country which refuses to ratify many other "international laws" (treaties) which most other countries agree to (and thus agree to be bound by).

Comment: @vartec WikiPedia tells me that there's also such a thing as [Customary international law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customary_international_law) ... but explicit treaties are more important: `Treaties and conventions are the persuasive source of international law and are considered "hard law."`

Comment: One problem with this question is that you make an unwarranted leap from the quote, "should be abiding by **international law**", to your specific question, "Is there international law which requires countries to extradite **other countries' dissidents**". There are various laws which do require extradition of **suspected criminals**. Did the USA charge Snowden with the crime of "**dissidence**"?

Comment: @ChrisW: was any dissident charged with such a crime?

Comment: `was any dissident charged with such a crime` -- An answer to that might be [YES "dissidence" used to be a crime in the Soviet Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissident#Eastern_bloc_dissidents) whereas [NO the First Amendment implies that "dissidence" has never been a crime in the USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). Snowden has actually been charged with ...

Comment: [three felonies including theft of government property and leaking official State secrets](http://www.politico.com/story/2013/06/edward-snowden-charged-nsa-93179.html), not including treason. The fact that some people label him "dissident" is slightly relevant to his situation; it's just one of many other allegations. I don't see reason to believe that Obama was thinking in those terms ("Snowden is a dissident") when he said what you quoted about **international law**: I doubt that Obama was talking about "dissidence", and so I don't understand why or what you are asking about "dissidence".

Comment: Considering your most recent comment to rob's answer which was, `being a dissident means, that the country which would take decision on extradition, would consider charges to be politically motivated, which renders request for extradition invalid`, perhaps what you meant to ask is exactly the opposite question, "is there any international law which **protects** 'dissidents' or people accused of 'political crimes' from being extradited?"

Comment: @ChrisW: actually I've change the question not to include word "dissident", since it creates too much controversy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no extradition treaty between the US and Russia. [The state department FAQ](http://www.state.gov/s/l/treaty/faqs/70138.htm) says,

> Where can I find a list of countries with which the United States has
>   extradition treaties?
>
> You may find a list of these countries at 18 U.S.C. § 3181.

The link is to http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/71600.pdf, which makes no mention of Russia. So if you're prepared to accept the US Government's word for it, Russia is not a country with which the US has an extradition treaty.

---

Anyway I don't believe that what you quote actually contains a claim by Obama that Russia is not abiding by international law. It certainly doesn't specify what the legal nature of the breach might be, if there is a breach involved either in "talking about potentially offering Snowden asylum", or in actually offering it. It doesn't claim that Russia would be required to extradite.

What it says is, that Russia should abide by international law. Or, literally, it just says that it is expected that they will recognise that they should abide. This "claim" is of course true as far as it goes, which isn't far.

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims. There are a lot of claims here, and only a single Wikipedia page to support them.

Comment: @Oddthinking Could you identify which claims need references? IMO it's difficult to know what needs referencing and what's common knowledge.

Comment: I entirely agree that this answer is under-referenced for what it says, but also I don't know what requires reference. The reference I gave (admittedly only Wikipedia) was specifically because that part addresses the actual question asked. It was not intended to support the whole piece. I don't know what else is a "significant claim" in the context of this question. I intended any or all of it as leads for someone to look further into the potentially-relevant international law. But by the nature of what Obama said, I can't speak to his "notable claim", only things he *might* be on about.

Comment: Unfortunately one good way to write a well-referenced answer is to pretend that you don't know a subject and cannot write about it yourself, and instead read a bit of https://www.google.com/search?q=international+law to find juicy/relevant block-quotes which you can piece together into an answer. Alternatively find someone who is [peer-reviewed and expert](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-is-photographic-evidence-theoretical-and-not-empirical#comment8385_2983) (and more authoritative than the president), whose is writing about this specific subject, and quote them.

Comment: @ChrisW: Well, I don't want to be too egotistical here. I've never formally studied the subject. Which is probably why I'd find it very gruelling to properly source everything I've said, other than by doing what I sort of expect readers to do with the parts they find most interesting/relevant: stick 'em into Google and find out much more than than the general knowledge I've collected here. If this makes the "long answer" unsuitable for the site then that's fair enough, I'm not going to complain just because there are other bad answers out that that pass this test my answer fails :-)

Comment: "Just go Google it" isn't an acceptable response because (a) then your answer (and this site) is redundant - they could just Google it. In fact, hopefully many readers are here *because* they Googled it. (b) We know that different people find different things when they Google. (See also "I've researched it!" comments from anti-vaxxers.

Comment: "I've never formally studied the subject. Which is probably why I'd find it very gruelling to properly source everything I've said" - Surely that is a textbook example of when references are absolutely required! :-)

Comment: "There's no extradition treaty between the US and Russia" - you reference this by showing that there used to be one, but you haven't shown there isn't one now.

Comment: "There is no international equivalent of statute law" - That seems to be the crux of the answer, but is unreferenced.

Comment: Your famous examples of treaties should be easy to reference, and particularly your claims about them.

Comment: "Bilateral treaties often lack the consensus nature of what we usually call law" I don't know what that means, but it is certainly a claim. Reference it. "generally lack a body equivalent to a court" That's a surprising claim. Reference it well.

Comment: "customary international law" - first time I have ever heard that term or that concept. How do I know if you just made it up? Answer: Reference it.

Comment: I think I've given enough examples. Keep going through the essay in a similar manner. In general, remove all the sentences that say "As far as I am aware". It is an "arguing from ignorance" fallacy. They aren't definitive.

Comment: It's not OK to post a knowingly unreferenced post and fixing it later. This means that: we have low-quality material for everyone to see on site; the *community* is under pressure to fix this instead of you; *moderators* get more work because they need to check back on this.

Comment: Because of the reason above I am deleting this until you fix it, and flag it.

Answer (score 1):

Tangentially relevant is that even when there are "international laws", they are subject to dispute and interpretation. Here's one well-documented example of that:

[USA Today: Swiss free Roman Polanski; won't extradite director to U.S.](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/life/people/2010-07-12-polanski-extradition-decision_N.htm)

> The Swiss mostly blamed U.S. authorities for failing to provide
>   confidential testimony...
>
> The stunning decision could end the United States' three-decade
>   pursuit of Polanski, unless he travels to another country that would
>   be willing to apprehend him and weigh sending him to Los Angeles.
>   France, where he has spent much of his time, does not extradite its
>   own citizens, and the public scrutiny over Switzerland's deliberations
>   may dissuade other nations from making such a spectacular arrest.
>
> The [Swiss] Justice Ministry also said that [Swiss] national interests
>   were taken into consideration in the [Swiss] decision...
>
> Switzerland handles about 200 extradition requests a year and only
>   about 5% are rejected...
>
> The government said extradition had to be rejected "considering the
>   persisting doubts concerning the presentation of the facts of the
>   case."
>
> Beyond the legal confusion, Polanski's extradition is a complicated
>   and diplomatically sensitive because of Polanski's status as a
>   cultural icon in France and Poland...

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not someone is a dissident is an extremely broad question; however, the United States does have a [sizable number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_extradition_treaties) of [extradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extradition) treaties that are in place that require the signatory countries to detain and extradite individuals. In general the United States requires the standard of [dual criminality](http://definitions.uslegal.com/d/double-criminality/) in the treaties and as per the [fact sheet](http://london.usembassy.gov/gb140.html) on the [US-UK Extradition Treaty](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2003/jul/UK_USA_extradition.pdf),

> **The standards are the same in practice:**
>
> All extradition requests between the U.S. and UK must meet the same evidentiary standard:  probable cause.  All requests from the
>   U.S. must meet the standard of “reasonable suspicion” required under
>   UK law.    However, all requests from the U.S. must also be based on a
>   charging document that meets the “probable cause” standard required
>   under U.S. law.  This is the same standard that the U.S. requires of
>   extradition requests from the UK.  The panel reviewed the evidence and
>   concluded:  “There is no practical difference between the information
>   submitted to and from the United States.”
>
> **The relationship is one of parity:**
>
> The treaty is a “dual criminality” treaty.  No one can be extradited by either country unless the offense for which extradition
>   is requested is a crime in both countries and carries a prison
>   sentence of at least one year.

Comment: OK, but that's bilateral, not international law. Also not very representative example, as UK-US agreements go way beyond bilateral agreements US has with other countries.

Comment: @vartec - Well, international law pretty much consists entirely of of the bilateral and multilateral treaties that are signed between countries. International law in and of itself is entirely based upon the system of treaties between countries so extradition really does depend entirely upon what the treaties say.

Comment: `extradition really does depend entirely upon what the treaties say` -- and it apparently depends on how they're interpreted and implemented. For example, Hong Kong found the USA's paperwork deficient or insufficient, for long enough to allow Snowden to leave Hong Kong. Since then, the last I read, he's in the international transit area of Moscow airport, which has its own rules about what paperwork he needs to remain there and which is arguably outside Russia's borders.

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, I seem to recall that most for legal purposes, the international terminals at most airports are technically outside the national boarders and you don't officially enter the country until you clear customs control.

Comment: @rob: so a criminal can commit theft (say) with impunity so long as they never leave the transit lounge?

Comment: Sometimes (although not apparently in Moscow airport these days) you don't even need a transit visa for/from the country: if you stay in the international area, without clearing the customs and passport control lines. Also some American citizens have been calling some Russian citizens "criminal", and vice versa, for years! America and Russia don't agree on every aspect of each other's laws, and interpretation of international law. Extradition between the two countries isn't automatic. And there isn't any "international police force" who go around enforcing soi-disant "international law".

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick IMHO if any authorities wanted to, then: they could arrest you just for being/breathing there; remove you from the airport (into the country) and then imprison or try or deport you; or immediately expel you (via airplane) to the country of their choice. The point, however, is that there is limited and variated (not universal) "international law" which compels authorities (sovereign nations) to act that way when the USA requests it.

Comment: @ChrisW: We are in agreement. So far as I can tell, once you enter a nations airspace you are subject to it's laws. So called "International zones" in airports are not any kind of legal sanctuary, they are just an administrative convenience - you are deemed to have not yet *formally* entered the country but you are still subject to it's laws - including extradition.

Comment: The question is whether "being a dissident" is a crime in both Russia and the USA. The answer is almost certainly no. However being (or declaring oneself) a dissident is not a get-out-of-jail-free card for people who have committed crimes. Bin Laden challenged the established doctrines, policies and institutions of Saudi Arabia and was thus a dissident. I don't think this would have helped him if he chose to hang around in a transit lounge in an international zone at Kennedy international.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick My admittedly poor understanding of the laws involved is that in the international zone in a international airport you are not legally in the host country until you have cleared customs. This is mostly a legal convenience that is in place to allow for connecting flights through countries without requiring the passengers to receive visas from that country. However, my understanding is that due to his legal convenience the host nation isn't required to recognize you as being "in the country" so as long as you don't break any local laws they "don't have grounds" to arrest you.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick `you are deemed to have not yet formally entered the country but you are still subject to it's laws - including extradition` -- Yes. And he presumably chose to travel via Moscow in particular, instead of e.g. via London or Vancouver: because, the laws and law enforcement are different.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick `Bin Laden ... was a dissident. I don't think this would have helped him ...  in an international zone at Kennedy international`. Bin Laden was "a wanted man": wanted by the USA. Do you think that Russia "want" Snowden in the same way? I don't know, but if Snowden is "wanted" for "Revealing American State Secrets" or whatever the real reason is, that might not even be any kind of "crime", under Russian law.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: being dissident itself isn't a crime, all dissidents are formally charged with some other crime. Revealing secrets or espionage are quite typical charges. However, being a dissident means, that the country which would take decision on extradition, would consider charges to be politically motivated, which renders request for extradition invalid. Unless it's of course UK, which would gladly send foreign or even it's own citizens to Guantanamo.